# How to set excel cell as read-only using Laravel - Maatwebsite?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I want to download a report with sum of two columns to be displayed in another column. I want to make the answer cells to be read-only i.e., non-editable. How to make it using Laravel-Maatwebsite?

I have performed the sum formula.

```
$sheet->cell('C1', function($cell){
    $cell->setValue("=SUM('A1:B1')");
});
```

I looked for protect cell function but I couldn't find.

Comment: hai. . how did u do it ? Even i have the same requirement. can u please help with this

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution how you can use protected cell function

```
$sheet->protectCells('A1:F1', 'PASSWORD');
$sheet->getStyle('A2:F50')->getProtection()->setLocked(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
 // here in the place of F50 you can pass maximum range like F2000
$sheet->getDelegate()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
```

Though the question was asked like 3 years ago but this might help someone in future !